# What should be the padding token for a Huggingface model?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, huggingface-tokenizers

Should it be the eos token or the PAD token? I got this error message:

> ValueError: Asking to pad but the tokenizer does not have a padding
> token. Please select a token to use as `pad_token`
> `(tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token e.g.)` or add a new pad
> token via `tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': '[PAD]'})`.

So which of those tokens should I use?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76446228/setting-padding-token-as-eos-token-when-using-datacollatorforlanguagemodeling-fr